# Visio ERD cannot fit in A4

Tags: database, microsoft-visio, diagrams, erd

I did a reverse engineering on a Oracle database into Visio 2010, the issue is that I can't find anywhere to make the size of the entities to fit into an A4 format, entities won't shrink. Am I missing something?

[image: Visio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest simply making the page size as large as you needed it to hold the drawing. Then when you print it, set the print option so that it shrinks your now oversize page into the A4 format when it gets sent to the printer.